# Angular material tabs shows different behavior on latest version

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I am trying to create simple angular material tabs using latest release. But i am not getting the expected behavior of tabs.

```
Example - using angular v1.4.1

    http://codepen.io/navneet35371/pen/QbOqWy

Example using angular v1.3.15

    http://codepen.io/clairebones/pen/EjNeWY
```

You could see the animation using the latest version is not quite smooth.

Comment: You should probably post this on the AM issue tracker, not here. There are already several issues there regarding incompatibility with angular 1.4.1

Comment: raised the issue here.. https://github.com/angular/material/issues/3434